# How to check already date range inserted per month into db using sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How to check already date range inserted per month  into db using sql query

```
DECLARE @TODAY DATETIME
    DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME,@ENDATE DATETIME
    SET @STARTDATE= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    SET @ENDATE= DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))


    IF NOT EXISTS (select date  from table where date between @STARTDATE and @ENDATE)
```

IF (@D_INVOICE_DATE >= @TODAY)
BEGIN
---INSERT--
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'EXISTS'
END
but again and again inserted in db 
my required is per month only one record inserted in db based month wise

Comment: Column date datetime and your storage with time value? Examle '30 oct 2017 17:00:00'

Comment: You need to provide more detail about what you are trying to do here. You might also take a peek at this. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations Look specifically at the section about Date Parts.

Answer (score -1):

1. Convert datetime to date, but this kill using index

   IF NOT EXISTS (select * from table where CAST(date as date) between @STARTDATE and @ENDATE)
2. SET @ENDATE= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)

   IF NOT EXISTS (select * from table where date >= @STARTDATE and date < @ENDATE

Comment: Actually casting date(time) to the other one is a bit odd. It is actually totally sargable and does not inhibit index usage. It goes against the "don't use functions on a column" mantra but it is one of those rare cases where it is actually ok.

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #a
CREATE TABLE #a (Dt Datetime DEFAULT GETDATE() PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
SELECT Dt FROM #a WHERE Dt = GetDate()
SELECT Dt FROM #a WHERE CAST(Dt as date) = GetDate()

Comment: @Sean Lange compare two plan and his predicate

Comment: That isn't a valid test. This is running two select statements against a table with a single column and no rows. BTW, they both have an index seek. Want a few links to demonstrate? http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/ another https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable Of course there is a caveat. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea

Comment: @single column@ more column change execution plan this query? Okey

Comment: HI, i already inserted date '2017-11-03 12:59:59' i need to check this month date and current date not accepted to insert ,because already inserted this month.its accepted to insert next month

Comment: Regardless of the columns there is no rows so looking at the execution plan is pointless. Try looking at some of the links I posted.

Comment: add 1kk rows to the table and look

Comment: my column name PODATE datetime,i checked above mentioned query is not working